# How to show different blocks by MySQL value in EJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ejs

in my Node.js project, I have a table in which I want to color the status of values. For all status values, I have already set a JS variable which should replace the MySQL output.

After a long search I have no idea how to set in a JS variable in a table who can only be displayed with a specific color.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr class="table-info">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        <% if (data) { 
            console.log("Anzahl Datensätze: " + data.length);
            data.forEach(function(game){
```

What can I do to have these variables display the MySQL value as a color in the table column?

```
            var green = 'style: "background-color: #00ff00"';
            var red = 'style: "background-color: #ff0000"';
```

```
        %>
        <tbody id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td><%= game.g_name %></td>
                <td><%= game.g_status=='1'?red:green %></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <% }) %>
        <% } %>
</table>´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you were generating your html code was wrong. By replacing either `green` or `red` variable in your code, the `<td>` element would look like this:

```
<td>style: "background-color: #00ff00"</td>
```

In order to obtain the desired effect, one simply needs to put the style of the element inside the element whose colour needs to be changed, like:

```
<td style="backgorund-color: <% game.g_status === '1' ? '#ff0000' : '#00ff00'%>">your data</td>
```

This way, the html code generated will be:

```
<td style="backgorund-color: #ff0000">your data</td>
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!